What was the teaching of the Nicolations that is referred to in Rev 2:6 and Rev 2:15?
I have read in Acts 6:5 that Nicolas was a convert to Christianity.  I also read in https://renner.org/article/who-were-the-nicolaitans-and-what-was-their-doctrine-and-deeds/ that he was also a convert to Judaism from paganism, so he had roots in all three. His teaching blurred the line of separation between paganism and Christianity. I'm looking for reference material in the writings of early Church fathers to corroborate this hypothesis and expand on the false teachings that came forward.  I see this as very important because in two separate places messiah says that he hates this teaching.

We are not told so we do not know.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics. Excellent question and I suggest thinking about including quotes and references to your question to make the research to answer easier for us and to enhance possible nuances we might not have thought about.  Seeing the references in quotes in the question helps to clarify to everyone where your question is centered, too.

Thanks for the hint Rob.  Dan saw through my chaff and helped with references for me to follow up on.

The identification of the Nicolatians with Nicholas of Antioch needs to be taken with a grain of salt. It is true that several Church Fathers make that association but the Bible itself does not. It tells us only that Jesus praised the Ephesian church for hating them (Rev. 2:6) and that he criticized the church at Pergamum because "you also have some people who hold to the teaching of [the] Nicolaitans."
Regarding Nicholas of Antioch, the Bible informs us (Acts 6:3) that he was was a proselyte (a convert to Judaism) who was "filled with the Spirit and wisdom," and thus deemed worthy to be appointed as a deacon.
More than a century after Nicholas lived, both Irenaeus (Against Heresies 1.26.3; 3.10.6) and Clement of Alexandria (Miscellanies, 3.4.25f) "consider Nicolas of Antioch to be the founder of the Gnostic sect known as the Nicolaitans." Hippolytus, adds that Nicolas "departed from sound doctrine, and was in the habit of inculcating indifferency of both life and food" (Refutation of All Heresies, 7.24). This reinforces Clement's claim that Nicolas became an ascetic and that his followers later perverted his teachings to encompass idolatry and immorality (2.20.12). The church historian Eusebius of Caesarea writes that Nicolas himself was a moral man (Ecclesiastical History, 3.29). source
Conclusion: The church from the 2nd-4th centuries associated the Nicolatians with the teaching of Nicholas of Antioch, understanding it to be a gnostic heresy that saw the physical body is an illusion. This led either to extreme asceticism or its opposite, depending on which Church Father is consulted, so we are left to guess at what fruit this heresy might have born in practice. The Bible itself tells us little about this doctrine.

It's possible that it could lead to either extreme asceticism or its opposite at the same time.  This has been noted of several such heresies:  it calls you to extreme asceticism, and does not differentiate between other states, so that marriage is not different from random promiscuousness.

Thank you for the references Dan.

@Mary - Yes, although I doubt that those who practice this kind of thing would consider what they do random. More likely, they would be drawn only to people of a similar spirituality and even feel that God had brought them together.

@DanFefferman  If all sexual union is wrong because bodily, obviously God is not bringing them together.  Fornication is, indeed, often regarded as better than marriage because it's not pretending there's nothing wrong with it.


The early church's choice of "Nicholas of Antioch" as one of the first
deacons implies he likely possessed natural abilities and leadership
qualities, as well as fulfilling the apostles' qualifications of being
"of good reputation, full of the Holy Spirit and wisdom" (Acts 6:3).
That Luke calls him a proselyte tells us that he was a Gentile who
converted to Judaism before his calling to Christianity.
Both Irenaeus and Clement of Alexandria consider Nicolas of Antioch to
be the founder of the Gnostic sect known as the Nicolaitians. Another
early writer, Hippolytus, adds that Nicolas "departed from sound
doctrine, and was in the habit of inculcating indifferency of both
life and food," meaning he taught the Gnostic belief of the
irrelevance of physical things. This reinforces Clement's claim that
Nicolas became an ascetic and that his followers later perverted his
teachings to encompass idolatry and immorality.
Though sincere and devout, he came to believe that the only way to
grow spiritually was to consider his body and its desires as
unimportant. His fundamental doctrine of asceticism appears to have
been "the flesh must be treated with contempt" in order to reach a
high level of spirituality.
Over the years, however, this teaching took on a more Gnostic spin:
Since the flesh is unimportant, even contemptible, what one does in
the flesh is of no consequence. Spiritual life, growth, and ultimately
salvation occur in the soul, and since God is spirit, He has no regard
for the flesh. Therefore, Nicolaitans reasoned, what does it matter if
one satisfies the flesh's desires? At some point then, Nicolaitanism
evolved from an ascetic philosophy to a licentious one—one that Christ
says He hates (Revelation 2:6, 15).
When members of the church teach and practice that they are not
obliged to keep the laws of God, sin will inevitably break out and
apostasy will increase.

Read more about Nicolaitans, Judaizers, and Gnostics here:
http://stauffer-scribbler.blogspot.com/2018/09/judaizers-gnostics-and-nicolaitans.html

Good information, but when you quote at length from a source you should indicate that you have done so. (not to mention that the blog from which you quoted seems to have copied extensively from this source without attribution)

@DanFefferman thank you, that's the source I needed.
